# minicart ko in magento2

Tags: javascript, magento2.2, knockoutjs

**Js file**

```
qtyOptions: ko.observableArray([]),  
initialize: function () {
this._super();                 
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    this.qtyOptions.push(i);
}
return this;
```

**template file**

```
<!-- ko if: stockQty > 10 -->
<select data-bind="attr: {
     id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
     'data-cart-item': item_id,
     'data-item-qty': qty,
     'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
     }, value: qty, options: $parent.qtyOptions"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

How to get template stockQty value into js file like this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= stockQty; i++) {
    this.qtyOptions.push(i);
}
```